Conversational Product search using LLM
What we want is when the user asks for something, searches for the product in our database with millions of data, shows results then asks the user to give more details and then shows more relevant products etc. The chat continuation is just one part of it
Is there any way GPT can look at the data without much cost consumption
or should we use vectors for semantic search?

To save on costs, you could always look at HuggingFace as an alternative to OpenAI. I've built a conversational chatbot using NASA Astronaut data as a knowledge base. You could probably do the same with your product data.
And yes, I would absolutely use a vector store to support a localized context. In my example below, I'm using Astra DB as a vector database to store the context.
Now, as you have not posted any code, I'm going to make some assumptions. Essentially, instead of using OpenAIEmbeddings you can use HuggingFaceEmbeddings and specify an open source model like all-MiniLM-L6-v2. Then if you're using LangChain you can specify the embeddings model in your vector store definition, and build your chain like you would with OpenAI:
llm = HuggingFaceHub(
    repo_id="HuggingFaceH4/zephyr-7b-beta",
    task="text-generation",
    model_kwargs={
        "max_new_tokens": 512,
        "top_k": 30,
        "temperature": 0.01,
        "repetition_penalty": 1.03,
    },
)
# init LLM and embeddings model
embeddings = HuggingFaceEmbeddings(
    model_name="sentence-transformers/all-MiniLM-L6-v2",
    model_kwargs={'device': 'cpu'},
    encode_kwargs={'normalize_embeddings': False},
)

astronaut_prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_template(astronaut_template)
vectorstore = AstraDBVectorStore(
    embedding=embeddings,
    collection_name=TABLE_NAME,
    api_endpoint=ASTRA_DB_API_ENDPOINT,
    token=ASTRA_DB_TOKEN,
    namespace=ASTRA_DB_KEYSPACE,
)
retriever = vectorstore.as_retriever(search_kwargs={"k": 3})

chain = (
    {"context": retriever, "question": RunnablePassthrough()}
    | astronaut_prompt
    | llm
    | StrOutputParser()
)

userInput = "which three astronauts flew on Apollo 11?"
print(chain.invoke(userInput))

Sometimes you can get rate-limited by HuggingFace, but you can use an API key from a free account to mitigate that. Have a look at my astronautRAG Git repo for more detail.
